# RubyMine アップデート方法

Tags: rubymine

RubyMineのアップデート方法を公式ホームページから探したのですが見つかりません。
単純に最新版をダウンロードして、旧版を削除すればいいのでしょうか？
その場合RubyMineに入れたプラグインは要再ダウンロードでしょうか？

なお私が使用しているRubyMineはバージョン7.1.4です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

年に一回あるかないかの作業なのでハッキリと覚えていませんが、https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/ からDownloadボタンをクリックしてインストーラ（dmgファイル）をダウンロードした気がします。

プラグインも再インストールしたような記憶があるので、使っているプラグインをメモしておいた方が良さそうです。
また、最悪昔のバージョンに戻れるように、今使っているRubyMineをリネームして、上書きコピーされないようにしておくことをオススメします。

あと、ヒープメモリの設定を変更している場合は再度変更が必要になります。

インストール後に `/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/bin/rubymine.vmoptions` をテキストエディタ等で編集してください。

参考： [RubyMineのヒープメモリを増やす · Yoshi's Notes](http://blog.sato0123.com/2015/03/10/RubyMine_HeapMemory/)

Comment: 8.0.1にアップデートできました。アップデート時に前回の設定を引き継ぐかという項目がありYESを選択したところプラグインはどうやら引き継ぎできたみたいです。やはり`rubymine.vmoptions`は初期設定になってました。

Answer (score 0):

メニューから　RubyMine > Check for Updates
はいかがですか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Check for Updatesからはプラグインのアップデートしかみあたりませんでした。